# Changing color scale in KML files?

Tags: kml, google-maps-api, color, color-ramp, colormap

I want to work with kml/kmz files in the Google Maps API, but I want to remap the color scales.

Is that possible?

Here are example kml/kmz files where I'd like to change the color representation of the data, but I don't see any method to do so.  I can see them fine using Google Earth or the Google Maps API.

- world population density:
  https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/servlet/RenderData?si=875430&cs=rgb&format=KMZ&width=3600&height=1800
- world topography:
  https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/servlet/RenderData?si=196466&cs=rgb&format=KMZ&width=3600&height=1800
- US current snow depth:
  http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snow_model/GE/latest_nsm_depth.kmz

Answer (score 1):

The three KMLs you linked to all use image overlays to display the data, so the colors are built into an image file that they are laying on the map. One way to re-color them would be to try and extract the image(s) from the KML file, and re-color in some image editing software. But the better way to do it is probably to try and find the source data, re-style it in your GIS software (QGIS, ArcGIS, etc.), and export your own KML/KMZ.